# Python - Cannot find file in system path?

Tags: python, file-io, directory

I am trying to move into Python and am used to using MATLAB. In MATLAB I am used to adding folders to the current working directory or path. So I would normally add a particular folder + all the sub folders. Then when I want a particular file (.csv or .m) that is in one of those folders I can just call it without having to generate full path names.

I wanted to do this in Python but seem to be getting stuck:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os as os
import sys as sys
```

I had to expunge the real paths because of names and customer names. However, I am in a particular directory where my scripts are and then I wanted to add two folders so I could access data files. I used this:

```
paths = ["/path/to/dir1","/path/to/dir2"]

for path in paths:
    if OS.path.exists(path) and OS.path.isdir(path):
        sys.path.append(path)
    else:
            print(f"Warning: {path} is not valid")
```

This runs with no errors. I check with:

```
print(OS.getcwd())
print(sys.path)
```

the full and correct directories are shown.

When I run:

```
cwd = OS.getcwd()
files = OS.listdir(cwd)
```

I get the files in the current working directory

When I run:

```
files = OS.listdir(paths[1])
print(files)
files = OS.listdir(paths[2])
print(files)
```

I get the list of all the files in my two new folders. Present and correct.

When I come to load a file, say a .csv that I know is in path 2:

```
can_log = pd.read_csv("RDE_cold_20210331_Resampled.csv")
```

I get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'RDE_cold_20210331_Resampled.csv'
```

I moved the file to the cwd and then it runs fine, so I guess it is only looking into the current working directory. So what have I done wrong here? have I misunderstood adding folders to path?

Comment: `sys.path` is strictly for the import system to search for modules, nothing else.

Comment: I agree with @blhsing, I am also writing an answer to the question

Comment: @blhsing ah I see, so this would be purely for .py files?